# Copy images from iPhone to app

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, image, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to copy images from the images iphone library to my app ? 
Or get the address so i can load it again from the library ?

Comment: by copying to you mean actually loading them into the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@poupou is right you do need to use UIImagePickerController, but i don't think he noticed you wanted help with it on mono touch.

However, I was in a similar situation before and i still have this favorited from a while back. [Screen Cast Using UIImagePickerController](http://www.martinbowling.com/post/Screen-Cast-Using-UIImagePickerController-in-MonoTouch.aspx)

I found it very helpful, and if i read your post write, this should be exactly what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the great video, help with another problem. But the main problem is that im making an recipe app there all the information i saved in a SQLite. But i want to save the image as well(Maybee not in an SQLite database. But have do i get the image either copy'ed to my app ore access the image the i load an recipe again??

Comment: If its a recipe app, wouldn't you want the user to choose the image and then save that with the other data, or am I just understanding you wrong

Comment: Yes that's correct. I want the user to choose an image og save it with the rest of the data.

Comment: Okay this should help http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/02/sqlite-tutorial-saving-images-in.html it's in objective C but it's not to bad to convert over it's the "Saving image in the SQLite database" and the section afterwards looks like it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

You can access images, like photos, by either using:

- [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) which allows you to pick an image; or
- [`ALAssetLibrary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html) which allows you to enumerate all assets (including images) that are stored on your iPhone. Dimitris has a nice [sample](http://software.tavlikos.com/2011/02/13/assetslibrary/) (**update: link fixed**) on how to do this on his excellent blog.